# DOJO: How to pass model/pojo to spring mvc controller from jsp page

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am using DOJO and I want to pass POJO to my controller, I am new to DOJO and don't know how to create POJO in script and add values in it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 var grid = new (declare([ Grid, Pagination, Selection ]))({
                    collection : new RequestMemory({
                        target : 'getCashFlowListForApproval'
                    }),
                    columns : structure,
                    className : 'dgrid-autoheight',
                    loadingMessage : 'Loading data...',
                    noDataMessage : 'No results found.',
                }, 'grid');
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring with dgrid, I used a Restful webservice, instead of MVC, so I could bypass the view/templating engine, as that makes things more complicated.  Here is a link to the sample project I created:  https://github.com/jumpnett/spring-boot-dojo

It's based off of these docs:

1. http://dgrid.io/tutorials/1.0/hello_dgrid/
2. http://dgrid.io/tutorials/1.0/grids_and_stores/
3. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I used the rest-service guide to generate the json that the dgrid consumes.  It's a List that's serialized as JSON.  The target is just the url, that the rest controller is mapped to using request mapping.